# Handling multiple https requests from node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I've hunted around on SO for help on this and I've been going around in circles for a while but I'm stuck

I'm making multiple ReST POSTS using node.js https and I need to be able track the responses for each request and then aggregate the results.  The number of requests that I perform each time varies.

I've created a function that returns a Promise for each http request.

```
function httpRequest(params, postData) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var reqActivity = http.request(options, function(res) {                             

            if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode + ' statusMessage=' + res.statusMessage));
            }

            var chunks = [];
            res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                console.log("Blowing chunks...");
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on("end", function() {
                console.log('At the end');
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                var response = JSON.parse(body);                     
                var errorMessage;
                if (//checking for some specific messages in the response) {
                    errorMessage = "stuff that went wrong";
                    reject(errorMessage);
                }
                resolve(body);                                
            });

            res.on("error", function(error) {
                console.log("in error");                                    
                reject(error);
            });     

            reqActivity.write(postData);                                    
            reqActivity.end();
         });                        
    });
};
```

Then I need to call this function multiple times and handle the returned promises but if I do it like this I don't see how I can handle multiple returns

```
httpRequest(options, JSON.stringify(bulkUpdateObj)).then(function(output) {
    console.log(output);
    // Do stuff
});
```

Which makes me think I need to build up an array of promises.  Would that look like this?

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(httpRequest(options, JSON.stringify(bulkUpdateObj)));
```

If so, how do I use Promise.all to check things?  Or is that indeed the right way to do it?

Any help, greatly appreciated, as always!

**UPDATE**
So I've implemented the Promise array with Promise.all like so:

```
Promise
.all(promises)
.then(values => {
    console.log("Inside of Promise.all - promise length: " + promises.length);
    console.log("Values: " + values);
})
.catch(reason => {
    console.log("Inside of error of Promise.all - promise length: " + promises.length);
    console.log("Reason: " + reason);
});
```

But I'm continually getting the message: 
(node:61289) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 14):

To me it looks like I am handling the rejection, what could be causing this?

Comment: Yes, you use `Promise.all()` to track when an array of promises are all done.  That is the right way to track when multiple promises are all done.

Comment: this sounds like a good problem for a logging module. write a module that takes output and does whatever aggregation you want with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all looks close. `Promise.all()` should be able to handle the rest.

Once you have an array of promises pushed into `promises`you can:

```
Promise.all(promises)
.then(result => {
   //result will be an array of values returned from your requests
}
.catch(err => {
    // whoops.
}
```

The only catch is that if one of your requests rejects, it will stop everything immediately and reject the whole thing. Maybe that's what you want, but if not you might prefer resolving some sort of error, which will then end up in the results array

Comment: Thanks - so if I'm looping around calling the httpRequest function multiple times and pushing the promises into an array e.g.

    promises.push(httpRequest(options, JSON.stringify(bulkUpdateObj)));

Then I use Promise.all to check the results, given that the http requests are asynchronous, how does Promise.all know that all the requests have completed and resolved?

Comment: From this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

It states: "But, Promise.all resolves synchronously if and only if the iterable passed is empty"

So, maybe that's the answer, as long as promises is nonzero length then it'll wait for the stack to empty?

Comment: Cracked it, I ran into the problem where the request.write didn't seem to ever get called.  
In the function I shared I was calling it within the wrong scope.  Next issue to solve, how to deal with sending 1000s of requests without running into connect ENFILE error...